# How to seperate from an overpowered empty

Tags: mesh, uv, objects, parent

a question from an experienced Blender user here... (So please assume I know what I am talking about)
One of the problems that has followed me greatest throughout my journey in Blender has been the disaster that is unparenting empties from objects and the ensuing chaos as the object mesh and texture rip each other apart.
How can I unpair an empty without causing any damage to my model? Is there a way I can almost reset the model mesh while keeping UV unwrap data?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Jet Winkelman. Brace yourself - expert answer is coming up. I am also very experienced and extremely skilled Blender user. I always know what I am talking about and never make mistakes. I am in fact one of the best there is in pretty much anything I do. So... yeah.

Comment: Please share your file, it's not clear why unparenting would damage the texture

Answer (score 1):

Unparenting an object from its parent does not change UVs, so good news there - there is nothing you need to do about UVs in that situation.

Unparenting is quite easy, you need to select the object and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>(you could also go to Object menu -> Parent -> Clear Parent), then choose Clear and Keep Transformation if you want the object to remain in the same global position, orientation and scale as it is while parented. You can unparent any type of object from any other type of object - it doesn't matter if the parent or the child is an empty.

[image]

If objects change some undesired, unexpected way when you unparent something, there must be some other things going on than just simple hierarchy in the scene. There are many ways objects can depend on other objects in Blender so it is hard to advise further without more information or a shared .blend file.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe the solution was so simple! Thank you!!

Comment: @Jet Winkelman if the answer is correct, mark it as so